# Ограничение нижнего порога при вычитании

Tags: c++, c

Как сделать так, чтобы при вычитании 2х чисел `uint32_t`, когда из меньшего вычитаем большее, в результате получался 0 ?

> Без if-ов, и желательно без операторов сравнения

Comment: Пиши результат в беззаноквый тип.

Comment: он и есть беззнаковый. нужно сделать так, чтобы не трогался CF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Ну и задачи ты, барин, ставишь..." (с) К/ф "Формула любви"

Есть одна загвоздка - требуется *знаковый* сдвиг, и чтоб он корректно работал, распространяя знак. Беда в том что формально это - implementation defined, хотя в большинстве реализаций работает верно.

Если так - то реализовать нужный вам "монус", он же `dozu(x,y)` можно так:

```
(x-y)&~(int((~x&y)|((~(x^y))&(x-y)))>>31)
```

Читайте Уоррен Г. *Алгоритмические трюки для программистов*, книга того стоит :)

Answer (score 2):

```
u32b sat_subu32b(u32b x, u32b y)
{
    u32b res = x - y;
    res &= -(res <= x);
    return res;
}
```

Подсмотрено [здесь](http://locklessinc.com/articles/sat_arithmetic/).

Answer (score 1):

Самым простым решением будет следующее:

```
auto sum = first > second ? first - second : 0;
```

if'ов нет, зато есть «нежелательный» оператор сравнения. Ну он нежелательный, но не запрещённый.

Можно сделать и другое решение, чтобы удовлетворить требованиям:

```
bool div = first / second;
auto sum = (first - second)*div;
```

if'ов нет, сравнений нет. Решение ужасное. Как и требования.

Comment: @aleks.andr, это неправда, мой код даст 8, в Вашем примере.

Comment: Мда, bool'омагия...

Comment: Тернарный оператор это же сокращенный if, думаю не это автор хотел.

Comment: @iksuy, тернарный оператор это тернарный оператор. А в задании чётко сказано — нельзя if, if'ов у меня и нет.